# How would you differentiate "self hate" from "insecurities?"

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Don't insecurities arise from self hate? For example if we are insecure about our face aren't we hating our face - hating ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-hating and insecurity are not the same.

Self-hatred or [self-loathing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-loathing) is an attitude in which one thinks he/she is not good as a person from various reasons and does not accept and love him/herself. No matter what the cause, at some point one needs to realize that self-hatred is a conscious attitude, so a decision.

Insecurity means that one is not confident about a certain personal characteristic or capability, which can make him/her anxious, but not necessary self-loathing. One can be insecure but still love and accept himself.

In summary, insecurity is a feeling one may not be able to overcome at times, while self-hatred is an attitude that can be changed.

Experiencing and accepting love from others can help one to start love him/herself and  to be more secure.